# Laravel - Show name instead of id

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade, laravel-models

I am trying to write some code, that displays data from a database in Laravel. But I have two table values linked to eachother with a foreign key, and when I try to show that on my page, it just shows the id and not the actual name. I saw in another stackoverflow question that you should define the table data values in ur Model, but that doesn't work or I did it wrong.
Can someone be so kind to help me fix this please? :)

Model Planet.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Planet extends Model
{
    public function solar()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo(SolarSystems::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

Model SolarSystems.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SolarSystems extends Model
{
    public function planet()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Planet::class, 'solar_systems_id');
    }
}
```

PlanetController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Planet;
use App\Models\SolarSystems;

class PlanetController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $planets = Planet::all();
        $solar = SolarSystems::all();

        return view('welcome', ['planets'=>$planets]);
    }
    public function show($planeet)
    {
        $planets = Planet::all();
        $solar = SolarSystems::all();
    
        $planets = collect($planets)->where('name', $planeet);
        return view('welcome', ['planets' => $planets]);
    }
}
```

welcome.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

@foreach ($planets as $planeten)
    <ul>
        <li>{{ ucfirst($planeten->name) }}</li>
        <p>{{ ucfirst($planeten->description) }}</p>
        <p>{{ ucfirst($planeten->solar_systems_id) }}
    </ul>
@endforeach
    </body>
</html>
```

import.sql:

```
CREATE DATABASE laravel;
USE laravel;
CREATE TABLE planets (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name text,
    description text,
    size_in_km int(11),
    solar_systems_id int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE solar_systems (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name text,
    age_in_years int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO planets (name, description, size_in_km, solar_systems_id)
VALUES ('mars', 'Mars is the fourth planet from the Sun and the second-smallest planet in the Solar System, being larger than only Mercury.', 3389, 1);

INSERT INTO planets (name, description, size_in_km, solar_systems_id)
VALUES ('venus', 'Venus is the second planet from the Sun. It is named after the Roman goddess of love and beauty.', 6051, 1);

INSERT INTO planets (name, description, size_in_km, solar_systems_id)
VALUES ('earth', 'Our home planet is the third planet from the Sun, and the only place we know of so far thats inhabited by living things.', 6371, 1);

INSERT INTO solar_systems (name, age_in_years)
VALUES ('The Milky Way', 1360000000);
```

This is what I get right now, but instead of the '1' it needs to say: 'The Milky Way'
[image]

Comment: Where is the relational table of the two tables ? Have you defined one that connects the two tables "planets" and "solar_systems"? Bear in mind that you need a specific key that is on both tables like the id of the solar_system for example. If you haven't set that, I think that you should first check how to set up a relational table and then set up your Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There few issues with your code;

#### Relationship

You have 1-N relationship, a Planet belongsTo a Solar System and a Solar System hasMany Planet.

**Planet.php**

```php
public function solar()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SolarSystems::class, 'solar_systems_id');
}
```

**SolarSystems.php**

```php
public function planets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Planet::class, 'solar_systems_id');
}
```

#### Controller

**PlanetController.php**

```php
public function show($planeet)
{
    $planets = Planet
              ::with('solar')
              ->where('name', $planeet)
              ->get();
       
    return view('welcome', ['planets' => $planets]);
}
```

Has you can see, I'm using `with` and `where` to optimize the query.

- `with` will eager load the relationship: [well explained in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
- `where` will add a criteria to the database query, which will perform more efficiently than a collection. [Usage](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses)

#### View

Since you have loaded the relationship with the eager loading, you can directly have access to the model from the planet.

```php
 <p>{{ ucfirst($planeten->solar->name) }}
```

Comment: Now it finally works, thank you so much man! :D

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
<p>{{ ucfirst($planeten->solar_systems_id) }}
```

with this line

```
<p>{{ ucfirst($planeten->solar()->name) }}</p>
```

Comment: This cause a N+1 issue that could easily be solved with [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: All I'm getting now is this error: 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name (View: C:\Users\mauro\OneDrive\Bureaublad\School\Bit Academy\18 Laravel\project\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)'

Comment: So use `Planet::with('solar')->get()` instead of `Planet::all()` , and there is no need for the brackets just `<p>{{ ucfirst($planeten->solar->name) }}</p> `

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line

```
{{ ucfirst($planeten->solar_systems_id) }} 

with this line 

{{ ucfirst($planeten->solar->name) }}
```

Because you need to get the name from the relationship

Comment: Like the other answer, this cause a N+1 issue that could easily be solved with [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `$planets = Planet::with('solar')->get();`